# Multiple file upload with PHP 8.1

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload multiple files.

html code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" id="uploadbtn" value="Upload">
</form>
```

php code to debug:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

results all good uploading 1 file:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test1.mp3
                )

            [full_path] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test1.mp3
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => audio/mpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/php9P4ENf
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3316453
                )

        )

)
```

result empty uploading 2 files:

```
Array
(
)
```

any ideas why is this happening?
is it common php 8.1 issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to change post_max_size in php.ini. Set and done!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).